# What is a simple means of proving that 3 vectors belonging to $\Bbb{R}^2$ are linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For my linear algebra class, there is a 2 part problem that asks, given the set {(1 2), (-1 -1), (1 0)}, prove or disprove that it is linearly independent using the definition only AND then prove or disprove that it is linearly independent "with a quicker proof that uses more than just the definition". For the first part I disproved that it is linearly independent by providing a counterexample, but for the second part I don't know what to do. My gut tells me that you can't have more than 2 linearly independent vectors that belong to  $\Bbb{R}^2$ (since the rref of a matrix with these vectors as columns could have at most 2 pivots), but I don't know how to express this in a proof.

Comment: If you can write $(0,0)$ as a linear combination of your three vectors with nonzero scalars, would that do?

Comment: That's what I did in the first part with the counterexample, but apparently my professor is trying to get us to prove it in some other way.

Comment: Ok,put your three vectors in a matrix. Perform Row Reduction Echelon Form and think of free variables. How many free variables do you have? And what does that mean in terms of linear (in)dependence?

Comment: Seems overly complicated. Why not just mention dimensions and bases/geometry?

Comment: Yes, it is, but the OP's professor wanted to see something else. So showing that there is a free variable would be another way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that what he was looking for was some quick statement based on the following proposition: Let V be an n-dimensional vector space. If {$u_1$, ... , $u_p$} $\subset$ V and p > n, then {$u_1$, ... , $u_p$} is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 2):

If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent, you're done. If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent  then $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is  a basis for $R^2$ so there are reals $x,y$ with $v_3=x v_1+y v_2.$

Answer (score 0):

The question might be looking for this:

$$\begin{align*}
a\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-1\end{pmatrix} + c\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&1\\
2&-1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$
Without solving for $a,b,c$, just by observing the dimensions of the matrix, we know there are non-zero solutions.

This is because the rank of the matrix is at most $2$, by rank-nullity theorem, the null space is at least $1$-dimensional, i.e. contains solutions other than $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: This is probably what he's looking for, something that incorporates other theorems about matrices, so I'll go with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $a_i$ are linear dependent if there is a non-zero solution $\lambda_i$ for the linear combination
$$
0 = \sum_i \lambda_i a_i
$$
meaning that at least one of the $\lambda_i$ is not zero.

In your case the above equation turns into:
$$
0 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\lambda_1
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}
+
\lambda_2
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
+
\lambda_3
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Can you spot a solution in this form?
$$
\lambda_2
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
 = 
\lambda_1
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}
+
\lambda_3
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$